# How to avoid converting svg to data-uri in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I need to use an inline SVG so I can animate it, but the SVG is less than 10KB so Gatsby is converting it to a data-uri. Is there a way to tell Gatsby to not convert a particular resource to a data-uri?

Comment: Are you using [gatsby-plugin-react-svg](https://github.com/jacobmischka/gatsby-plugin-react-svg)?

Comment: Ah, no! I'll give that a shot!

Comment: What's the best way to install gatsby-plugin-react-svg? It doesn't look like it's a npm module.

Comment: I would suggest gatsby-plugin-svgr https://github.com/zabute/gatsby-plugin-svgr

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`gatsby-plugin-react-svg`](https://github.com/jacobmischka/gatsby-plugin-react-svg).

```
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-react-svg
```

Add the plugin to your `gatsby-config.js`, then in your code:

```babel
import Icon from './path/icon.svg';

// ...

<Icon />
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use [`gatsby-plugin-svgr`](https://github.com/zabute/gatsby-plugin-svgr).

Comment: This does not work on Gatsby v2. Do you know how to handle it with the new version ? Thx

Comment: @MarcDelalonde It does now!

Comment: Another option is https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg. See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/babel/ on how to add a custom Babel plugin to Gatsby.

Comment: And use a capitalised first letter or else nothing happens!  `<Logo/>` NOT `<logo/>`.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Fabian Schultz's answer

There is Gatsby v2 support for [gatsby-plugin-react-svg](https://github.com/jacobmischka/gatsby-plugin-react-svg) if you use the @next version

`npm install gatsby-plugin-react-svg@next --save`

There were 2 tickets opened in the repo

[Issue 4](https://github.com/jacobmischka/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/issues/4)

[Issue 7](https://github.com/jacobmischka/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/issues/7)